# How to Maintain Value of Previous Increment in Loop

Tags: java, loops, increment, decrement

Here is my code:

```
int yaya = 5;
int x = 10;
do {
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Vote Ballot");
     System.out.println("Below are the 2 Canditates you can choose to vote from");
     System.out.println("Mar Roxas --- Code: 11");
     System.out.println("Duterte ---- Code: 12"); 
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Who do you vote? Enter numbers only!"); 
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if (choice == 11) 
     {

         System.out.println("You have voted Mar Roxas and not Duterte");

     }
     else if ( choice == 12 ) 
     {

         System.out.println("You have voted Duterte and not Mar Roxas");

     }
     else 
     {

         System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number");

     }
     String confirm = "confirm";
     String deny = "deny";
     int conf = 1;
     int den = 2;
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Do you want to let another voter vote? Or would you like to end the program at hand?");

     int ans = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if ( ans==1 )
     {

         System.out.println("The program would now repeat");

     }
     else if ( ans==2 ) 
     {

          if ( choice ==11 )
          {
              int RoxasC = 0;
              int DuterteC = 0;
              RoxasC+=1;

              System.out.println("Mar roxas recieved " +RoxasC+ " number of vote/s and Duterte Recieved " +DuterteC+ 
              " number of votes");

          }
          else if ( choice ==12)
          {
              int RoxasC = 0;
              int DuterteC = 0;

              DuterteC+=1;
              System.out.println("Duterte recieved " +DuterteC+ " number of vote/s Roxas received " +RoxasC+ 
              " number of votes");

          }
          System.out.println("Program will end as per request");
          break;

     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("You entered an invalid keyword program would still repeat");
     }

     System.out.println("\n");

} while( yaya==5 ); //Program Runs Infinitely
```

Here is my problem:

Let's say I run the program once and I choose to cast my vote for Mar Roxas. I enter the number 11. If I choose to stop the program, it tallies it up and says Mar Roxas gets one vote while the other guy gets 0. So far, so good. When I decide to choose to continue the loop, (which would re-run the program), it gets problematic.

When I decide to cast my vote on the other politician and decide to end the program, my initial vote on Mar Roxas becomes 0 and the Duterte gets 1.

How can I maintain the value of my previous votes when continuing the loop?

Comment: You initialize your integers to 0 inside the loop. As soon as you leave that `if` block, those variables will go out of scope. If you want to keep them, you have to declare them outside the loop.

Comment: @JosephAndrews Are you referring to my answer, or did you mean to respond to Arc676?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following actions needed to be taken:

- The vote counts for Roxas and Duterte need to be initialized outside of the do-while loop; this way, they don't reset back to zero within the loop.
- Increment the vote counters during voting instead of when counting up the results. This way, they can actually hold values greater than 1.
- Set `yaya` to a number other than 5 to break out of the loop (when voting has concluded).

---

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int yaya = 5;
int x = 10;
int RoxasC = 0;
int DuterteC = 0;

do {
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Vote Ballot");
     System.out.println("Below are the 2 Canditates you can choose to vote from");
     System.out.println("Mar Roxas --- Code: 11");
     System.out.println("Duterte ---- Code: 12"); 
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Who do you vote? Enter numbers only!"); 
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if (choice == 11) 
     {

         System.out.println("You have voted Mar Roxas and not Duterte");
         RoxasC++;

     }
     else if ( choice == 12 ) 
     {

         System.out.println("You have voted Duterte and not Mar Roxas");
         DuterteC++;

     }
     else 
     {

         System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number");

     }
     String confirm = "confirm";
     String deny = "deny";
     int conf = 1;
     int den = 2;
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Do you want to let another voter vote? Or would you like to end the program at hand?");

     int ans = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if ( ans==1 )
     {

         System.out.println("The program would now repeat");

     }
     else if ( ans==2 ) 
     {
          System.out.println("Mar Roxas received " +RoxasC+ " number of votes, and Duterte received " +DuterteC+ 
              " number of votes");

          System.out.println("Program will end as per request");
          yaya = 0;
          break;

     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("You entered an invalid keyword program would still repeat");
     }

     System.out.println("\n");

} while( yaya==5 ); //Program Runs Infinitely
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int RoxasC = 0;
int DuterteC = 0;

int yaya = 5;
   int x = 10;
    do{
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Vote Ballot");
     System.out.println("Below are the 2 Canditates you can choose to vote from");
     System.out.println("Mar Roxas --- Code: 11");
     System.out.println("Duterte ---- Code: 12"); 
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Who do you vote? Enter numbers only!"); 
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if (choice == 11) 
     { 

         System.out.println("You have voted Mar Roxas and not Duterte");


     } else if ( choice == 12 ) 
     {


         System.out.println("You have voted Duterte and not Mar Roxas");


     }
     else 
     {

         System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number");

     }
     String confirm = "confirm";
     String deny = "deny";
     int conf=1;
     int den=2;
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Do you want to let another voter vote? Or would you like to end the program at hand?");

     int ans = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if ( ans==1 )
     {

         System.out.println("The program would now repeat");


          if ( choice ==11 )
          {  

              RoxasC+=1;

              System.out.println("Mar roxas recieved " +RoxasC+ " number of vote/s and Duterte Recieved " +DuterteC+ 
              " number of votes");

          } else if ( choice ==12)
          {


              DuterteC+=1;
              System.out.println("Duterte recieved " +DuterteC+ " number of vote/s Roxas received " +RoxasC+ 
              " number of votes");


          }


     }
     else if (ans==2 ) 
     {


          if ( choice ==11 )
          {  



              System.out.println("Mar roxas recieved " +RoxasC+ " number of vote/s and Duterte Recieved " +DuterteC+ 
              " number of votes");

          } else if ( choice ==12)
          {


              System.out.println("Duterte recieved " +DuterteC+ " number of vote/s Roxas received " +RoxasC+ 
              " number of votes");


          }
          System.out.println("Program will end as per request");
          break;


     } else
     {
         System.out.println("You entered an invalid keyword program would still repeat");
        }

     System.out.println("\n");

   }while( yaya==5 ); //Program Runs Infinitely
```

Comment: This is the first potentially correct solution; you're incrementing the counters during the loop if the voting should continue, so the vote counters will accumulate as the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.Actually you were re-initializaingg you counters again on every loop iteration so your RoxasC and DuterteC  counter were being re-initializad to zero on every loop iteration

```
int yaya = 5;
   int x = 10;
   int RoxasC = 0;
   int DuterteC = 0;
    do{
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Vote Ballot");
     System.out.println("Below are the 2 Canditates you can choose to vote from");
     System.out.println("Mar Roxas --- Code: 11");
     System.out.println("Duterte ---- Code: 12"); 
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Who do you vote? Enter numbers only!"); 
     int choice = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if (choice == 11) 
     { 
         RoxasC+=1;
         System.out.println("You have voted Mar Roxas and not Duterte");


     } else if ( choice == 12 ) 
     {

          DuterteC+=1;
         System.out.println("You have voted Duterte and not Mar Roxas");


     }
     else 
     {

         System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number");

     }
     String confirm = "confirm";
     String deny = "deny";
     int conf=1;
     int den=2;
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     System.out.println("Do you want to let another voter vote? Or would you like to end the program at hand?");

     int ans = input.nextInt();
     System.out.println("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=");
     if ( ans==1 )
     {

         System.out.println("The program would now repeat");



     }
     else if (ans==2 ) 
     {


          if ( choice ==11 )
          {  



              System.out.println("Mar roxas recieved " +RoxasC+ " number of vote/s and Duterte Recieved " +DuterteC+ 
              " number of votes");

          } else if ( choice ==12)
          {



              System.out.println("Duterte recieved " +DuterteC+ " number of vote/s Roxas received " +RoxasC+ 
              " number of votes");


          }
          System.out.println("Program will end as per request");
          break;


     } else
     {
         System.out.println("You entered an invalid keyword program would still repeat");
        }

     System.out.println("\n");

   }while( yaya==5 ); //Program Runs Infinitely
```

Comment: Haseeb, while you're on the right track for initializing the vote counters outside of the do-while loop, you're missing something; when, in your code, do the vote counters get incremented?

Comment: RoxasC+=1; and DuterteC+=1; in the if condition will increment the counters whenever the condition become true. @chrisForrence

Comment: Alright, and in which if-condition? The one that casts the vote, or the one that determines if voting continues?

Comment: check the new edit now code should work fine now. @Chris Forrence